# Getting Funny Console Message From iPhone Simulator Using MKMapView

Tags: iphone, ios, mkmapview

Ey guys, I am running OS X 10.6.4 with Xcode version 3.2.4 and have an app that uses the MKMapView with MKOverlays and MKAnnotations. When in the map view, moving the map around(in and out of the viewing screen for both overlays and annotations) caused a few of these lines to pop up on the console:

```
/SourceCache/GoogleMobileMaps_Sim/GoogleMobileMaps-257/googlenav/mac/Loader.mm:172 Incorrect protocol version. We got 15464, but were expecting 14.
```

These messages didn't cause the application to crash or act any differently, but I was wondering what they meant and if there was any way of getting rid of them. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like some debugging cruft left behind from Apple -- I've seen the same thing. I would not worry about it at all.

Comment: Interesting... thanks for the response.